# Why is the browser running in circles and does not want to force the download of the PDF file in PHP?

Tags: php, file, pdf, download

I have created a script that allowed me to download docx, srt and pptx files and many others....

But problem, my script does not want to force the download of PDF files. The Chrome browser is running in circles and still doesn't want to launch the download of my PDF file.

**Here is my script:**

```
<?php
require_once 'includes/constants.php';

$pathFileUrl = '../'.WEBSITE_NAME_URL_FILES.'/docs/'.urldecode($fileUrl);

if (isset($fileUrl) && !empty($fileUrl) && file_exists($pathFileUrl)) {

    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME);
    $mime = finfo_file($finfo, $pathFileUrl);
    finfo_close($finfo);

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: '.$mime); //application/octet-stream
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($pathFileUrl).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($pathFileUrl));
    
    // Read file and send to browser
    readfile($pathFileUrl);
    exit;

} else {
    redirect(WEBSITE_NAME_URL);
}
```

**Can you please tell me where the error is coming from?**

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: What does the browser's dev tools' network tab say you actually get as response headers?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans 'Pomax' Kamermans How can I see their answers?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans 'Pomax' Kamermans Ah I see now. I think it's because of the accents in the filename. Here it is: "content-disposition: attachment; filename="Men sa wap bezwen pou achte sou entÃ¨nÃ¨t-ht-en.pdf" . How can I solve the problem of accents in the filename please?

Comment: @KJ that's a really weird description, and factually incorrect. But the encoding part is true: remember to url-encode this type of data. In this case, instead of `basename($pathFileUrl)`, just use `urlencode(basename($pathFileUrl))`

Comment: @KJ Which on modern computers with an understanding of unicode will work just fine everywhere.

Comment: Thanks guys for your answers. But I managed to solve it by myself. The problem was coming from my .htaccess file that I had inserted pdf in ```RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}!(\.pdf|\.webp|\.png|\.jpg|\.ico|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.zip|\.css|\.svg|\.json|\.js|\. wav)``` Because of this my PDF file could not be downloaded, now I just solved it and it is now like this: ```(\.webp|\.png|\.jpg|\.ico|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.zip|\.css|\.svg|\.json|\.js|\.wav)```.

Comment: `if (isset($fileUrl) && !empty($fileUrl)` - that combination of isset & empty is superfluous - empty encompasses everything that isset does already. And you already _accessed_ `$fileUrl` in the line before this, so this check is coming too late to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe What exactly do you mean? Can you be more clear and precise?

Comment: empty already includes the checks that isset performs. And you did `$pathFileUrl = '...'.urldecode($fileUrl);`, _before_ you even performed that check. So if `$fileUrl` was not set, that would cause an "undefined variable" warning/notice at that point already.